# PHPStorm property-read for Yii model relations

Tags: yii, phpstorm

How can I do this in PHPStorm so hinting works correctly when calling the `model()` method?

For instance:

```
/**
 * @property-read \Stores $store
 */
class Items extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array('store' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Stores', array('store_id' => 'id')),
    }
}

$items = new Items;
$items->store; // PHPStorm type hints this correctly

Items::model()->store; // PHPStorm does NOT type hint correctly.
```

Model above minimalist for focus of this post.

Comment: For your **particular** example -- add PHPDoc for `model()` method with `@return MyClass` in it

Comment: That did it. Any idea how to also do `Items::model()->findByPk($pk)->store` hinting?

Comment: Without help from Yii specific plugin (that knows how that framework works) -- I doubt. The whole type info is very dynamic here (known at run time only) and cannot be described using static type hinting using PHPDoc only.

Comment: Maybe actual Yii2 users who use PhpStorm can help you here. Consider asking similar question on Yii2 forums -- you should have better luck there.

Comment: @LazyOne sadly, I am stuck working with Yii 1.1 for this project. :( However, I did find the `YiiStorm` plugin just now but despite the promise of better relations integration, it doesn't do what I was hoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to 'tell' PhpStorm what this method returns.

```
    /**
     * @param $className
     * @returns Items
     */
    public static function model( $className = __CLASS__ ) {
        return parent::model( $className );
    }
```